# Formatar número com plugin Globalization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-cordova

Estou tentando utilizar o plugin `cordova.plugin-globalization` mas estou esbarrando na minha pouca experiência com Javascript.

xhtml:

```
<div>{{ item.valor | formataValor }}</div>
```

filter.js:

```
app.filter('formataValor',function(){
   return function(valor){
       console.log('globalization: '+valor)
       navigator.globalization.numberToString(
           valor,
           function (number) {
               console.log('numero formatado:' + number.value);
               return number.value;
           },
           function () {
               console.log('erro de formatacao de valor');
           },
           {type: 'currency'}
       );
   }
});
```

Aparentemente o retorno da função `navigator.globalization.numberToString` está se perdendo, pois a saída do console está ok.

Comment: As saídas no console estão ok (ex: "globalization: 123.4" e "numero formatado: 123,40"). O problema é que no html fica em branco.

Comment: GitHub: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization - Documentação: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-globalization/index.html

Comment: @Marconi aparentemente este plugin não funciona em browser... somente em devices Android/iOS e emuladores. Se vc for testar em browser o nvaigator.globalization estará undefined!